# Laravel 5 Route Model Binding is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to use Route Model Binding but got issues.

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->model('categories', 'App\Category');
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('categories/trash', ['as' => 'admin.categories.trash', 'uses' => 'CategoriesController@trash']);
Route::get('categories/{categories}/restore', ['as' => 'admin.categories.restore', 'uses' => 'CategoriesController@restore']);
Route::get('categories/{categories}/delete', ['as' => 'admin.categories.delete', 'uses' => 'CategoriesController@delete']);
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');
```

**CategoriesController.php**

```
public function restore(Category $category)
{
    $category->restore();
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function delete(Category $category)
{
    $category->forceDelete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**View**

```
 <a href="{!! URL::route('admin.categories.restore', $category->id) !!}">Restore</a>
 <a href="{!! URL::route('admin.categories.delete', $category->id) !!}">Delete Permanently</a>
```

But When I tried to `restore` or `delete` I got issue of `NotFoundHttpException`

[image]

Comment: I assume a category with an ID of 16 actually exists in your database?

Comment: Yes, there is data in database. http://prntscr.com/69lcsf

Comment: The row in question has been deleted. You can't use standard model binding to pick up deleted rows as far as I'm aware. If you want to do that you'd have to use `$router->bind('App\Category', function($category) {})` instead where the closure made use of Eloquent's `withTrashed` method. I suppose the above is assuming your model uses `SoftDeletes` and the column `deleted_at` is actually in use.

Comment: Thanks @BenSwinburne , It worked. It was because of softdeletes.

$router->bind('categories', function($id) {
            return Category::withTrashed()->find($id);
});

Comment: I created an answer so you can mark the question as answered and it'll disappear from lists of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot in your comments indicates that you're using `SoftDeletes`.

The following model binding code does not take deleted rows into account.

```
$router->model('categories', 'App\Category');
```

In order to accomplish this you'd need to use `bind` instead of `model`

```
$router->bind('categories', function($value)
{
    return App\Category::withTrashed()->where('id', $value)->first();
}
```

Which will include deleted rows. You'd need to use this for your restore route for example.